# Reporting RPC call progress

Tags: .net, progress-bar, servicestack, progress

I am developing an API server using the ServiceStack library on .NET 3.5 (a new experience for me), designed to be accessed by a Windows Forms thick client application. When the user clicks a button that results in a REST request to the server, I'd like to display a progress bar that shows the progress of the RPC call.

My services generally follow one of the following patterns:

- The client sends in a list of IDs, and expects to receive a list of objects, one object per ID. In this case, the progress percentage could be calculated as `(number of objects received so far) / (total number of objects requested)`
- The client sends in a request, and expects to receive a list of unknown length. On the service side, we retrieve the list of objects (from cache, database, calculation, whatever), serialize it, then write the serialized data to the HTTP response stream. In this case, the progress percentage could be estimated as `(number of bytes received so far) / (Content-Length of the HTTP response)`

In both cases, these lists could be quite long, and thus I expect them to take a nontrivial amount of time to be sent over the network.

Is there a way to accomplish this using ServiceStack's `JsonServiceClient`, `XmlServiceClient`, or any subclass of `ServiceClientBase` in general ? If not, what would be a good way to accomplish what I want without too much extra work ? I understand that I could write my own REST client implementation from scratch, but I'd rather avoid that if I can.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to take a look at pub/sub that ServiceStack provides. You could submit the initial request and return back a correlation identifier. Then you would want the thick clients subscribe to an event. The event could contain the data for the client to calculate the progress.

[ServiceStack Redis Pub/Sub](http://www.servicestack.net/docs/redis-client/redis-pubsub)

Comment: It seems like this would only work for Redis, whereas I need a generally applicable solution.

Comment: It's not a question of working 'for' Redis but that Redis is used to create the durable queues. As mythz said above, I believe that his answer more closely aligns with what you have described.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use [ServiceStack's service clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Clients-overview) which doesn't currently expose any way to tap into the downloading of urls to be able to report a progress bar.

I'd recommend using a [HTTP Client that does support progress updates](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/kirtan007/how-to-download-file-and-showing-its-progress-in-progress-bar/) to download a json string. To get JSON back from a ServiceStack service you can use the `Accept: application/json` HTTP Header or append **?format=json** to the QueryString.

Once the JSON string downloaded completely convert it into a DTO with:

```
var json = ...; //download with progress
var dto = json.FromJson<MyDto>();
```

Comment: Ack... I was afraid you might say that. So it looks like I'll be writing my own ServiceStack client after all. Is there at least an easy way for me to marshal the arguments ? I'd like to say something like, `var result = myClient.Post<CustomersResponse>(new GetDepartmentCustomers(1234), MyProgressHandlerFn)`. This is similar to how I'd use `jsonClient` today.

Comment: You just need to serialize the DTO to *marshall the arguments* i.e. `var jsonToPost = requestDto.ToJson();`

Comment: I see, so I serialize the DTO myself, then send the request manually and handle the response manually, that works. It seems like I will also need to essentially copy/paste the exception handling code from `ServiceClientBase` as well, correct ? Currently, the existing service clients will translate service-side exceptions for me, which is convenient...